# Go to next text box when enter is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Hello in my WinForms application i have this below program which helps to Go to next text box when enter key is pressed , But i am facing an issue here .
When I press enter key after I type something or without typing anything in first textbox it is going to next text box.
[image]
But if I type something accidentally and hit backspace to erase the first textbox content and if I press enter key then it is not moving to next textbox , Kindly help how to solve this issue.
[image]

My program:

```
private void Form_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
 {
     var b = new Button { TabStop = false, Left = -1000 };
    
     b.Click += ( s, a ) =>
     {
         SelectNextControl( ActiveControl, true, true, true, true );
    
         switch( ActiveControl )
         {
         case TextBox tb:
             tb.SelectAll( );
             break;
         case ComboBox cb:
             cb.SelectAll( );
             break;
         }
     };
    
     Controls.Add( b );
     AcceptButton = b;
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide the SelectNextControl method? Also, you should consider not having that much code in an event handler method, especially the Load event.

Comment: @GabrielStancu select next control method is that much only ...reference link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol?view=net-5.0#:~:text=The%20SelectNextControl%20method%20activates%20the,following%20list%20are%20not%20selectable.

Comment: @RAVI KUMAR, your problem is related to textbox entered key, but your code is related to button. Can you have a check and explain it?

Comment: @RAVIKUMAR My bad, haven't really worked that much with WinForms. But as Jack mentioned, your code is button related and your problem regards the textboxes. Please provide the textbox event handling (KeyPressed or something similar, I suppose).

Comment: Use a single event handler for all your TextBoxes, to handle the KeyDown event. If Keys.Enter is pressed, set `e.SuppressKeyPress = true`, then `SelectNextControl()`. Remove that Button.